# List all blobs with specific metadata in C#

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have my blob container where I have a custom metadata "Result" set to True for all blobs and due to some bad code writing, some blobs do not have these metadata set. I would like to list all such blobs who do not have "Result" as metadata or whose "Result" metadata value is anything other than True. Is it possible to write a c# code to do such filtering and return the list of Blobs? I couldnt find any example on internet.

I have just started writing the code and would like some help in completing it.

```
 var blobAccount = "<account>";
var apiKey = "<api-key>";
var containerName = "<container>";
var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(blobAccount, apiKey);

var account = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);
var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
 var blobAccount = "<account>";
var apiKey = "<api-key>";
var containerName = "<container>";
var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(blobAccount, apiKey);

var account = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);
var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
            var segmentSize = 20;
            List<CloudBlob> blobs = new List<CloudBlob>();
            try
            {
                // Call the listing operation and enumerate the result segment.
                // When the continuation token is null, the last segment has been returned
                // and execution can exit the loop.
                do
                {
                    BlobResultSegment resultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(string.Empty,
                        true, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, segmentSize, continuationToken, null, null);
                   // get the blob which its metadata does not container one 
                   var r = resultSegment.Results.OfType<CloudBlob>().Where(b => !b.Metadata.ContainsKey("type")).ToList();
                    blobs.AddRange(r);
                   
                      Console.WriteLine();

                    // Get the continuation token and loop until it is null.
                    continuationToken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;

                } while (continuationToken != null);
            }
            catch (StorageException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw;
            }
```